# Trouble binding functions/using lambdas to test message-passing code

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm sure this is a simple error, but I can't understand why the compiler is yelling at me like this.  The Signal has a method connect that designates functions to be called when the signal is emitted:
`Signal<Owner, TArgs...>::connect(const Handler& handler);`

In turn, Handler is just a typedef for functions:

`typedef function<void(const TArgs&...)> Handler;`

All of the signals are like this:

`ndn::util::signal::Signal<Rib, RibRouteRef> beforeRemoveRoute;`

What I need to do is to test that what the connected function actually receives is what was passed to the function that emits the Signal. I'm trying to lambdas to capture this and analyze it in the same function, but no matter what I do, I get compiler type conversion errors. The code I'm trying to use is:

```
  RibRouteRef routeInfo;

  std::function<void (RibRouteRef& rrrIn, RibRouteRef& rrrOut)> signalRec =
    [](RibRouteRef& rrrIn, RibRouteRef& rrrOut)
    { rrrOut = rrrIn; };

  rib.beforeRemoveRoute.connect(bind(&signalRec, _1, routeInfo));
```

Unless my understanding of bind() is grossly incorrect, what should be occurring is that bind() takes the lambda (wrapped in std::function, which I don't think I *need*), and takes its two parameters, binds one to always be routeInfo, and the other is the only parameter of the new, bound function. This new, bound function should have the signature of:`void (RibRouteRef&)`, right? However, the compiler error is:

```
../tests/rib/rib.t.cpp:360:33: error: no viable conversion from 'typename _Bind_helper<__is_socketlike<function<void (RibRouteRef &, RibRouteRef &)> *>::value, function<void (RibRouteRef &, RibRouteRef &)> *, const _Placeholder<1> &, RibRouteRef &>::type' (aka '_Bind<std::function<void (nfd::rib::RibRouteRef &, nfd::rib::RibRouteRef &)> *(std::_Placeholder<1>, nfd::rib::RibRouteRef)>') 
to 'const Handler' (aka 'const function<void (const nfd::rib::RibRouteRef &)>')
  rib.beforeRemoveRoute.connect(bind(&signalRec, _1, routeInfo));
```

I just have no idea what's wrong. Can anyone point out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your typedef isn't a separate template based on the code you have provided, so I assume it is using the TArgs... template parameter of Signal

If that is correct, then Owner becomes Rib and TArgs... becomes the single parameter RibRouteRef based on your Signal<>, which contradicts your declaration of the lambda requiring two RibRouteRef parameters.

I don't know what else it would break, but based on the limited code you provided, you would need to declare your Signal<> as something like:

```
ndn::util::signal::Signal<Rib, RibRouteRef, RibRouteRef> beforeRemoveRoute;
```

so the Handler type will include two RibRouteRef parameters rather than just one.

Note it states this in the error message (but in the most unreadable way possible), specifying that it cannot convert from what you provide (in these messages, skip the typename expansion and look at the aliased part beginning with 'aka' for the real type),

```
_Bind<std::function<void (nfd::rib::RibRouteRef &, nfd::rib::RibRouteRef &)> *(std::_Placeholder<1>, nfd::rib::RibRouteRef)>
```

to the declared type of

```
const Handler
```

with an expanded aliased type of

```
const function<void (const nfd::rib::RibRouteRef &)>
```

So, it is correctly telling you that it cannot convert your lambda with two RibRouteRef parameters to a lambda of one RibRouteRef parameter.

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned that, normally, these Signals are connected to functions that take only the one parameter. I can't change the Signal declaration. I thought that calling bind in the way that I am meant it would return a function object with only the one parameter? I was trying to do this with just a lambda and capture clause, but I was getting the same kind of error, and you can only use std::function to wrap a lambda with an empty capture clause.